# File Uploading with AJAX to dotnet Core

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, .net-core

I'm trying to upload a file to a .net core controller method but my 'file' parameter is null when the controller is triggered. This is the server side code...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadTimetable(long id, IFormFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileContent;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.ThrowIfNull(nameof(file)).OpenReadStream()))
            {
                fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            await routeService.UpdateFromTimetableAsync(id, CsvGenerator.FromString(fileContent));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Unable to process Timetable ({ex.Message})");
        }

        return Ok(new ApiServiceJsonResponse<Route>(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request, id, "routes"));
    }
```

The route is triggered fine but the value of 'file' is null.

I think the issue may be client side related as, looking in Chrome, I can see nothing in the AJAX request body. This is built up like this...

```
/**
 * An AJAX request wrapper.
 * Usage of this enables testing AJAX calls.
 * 
 * @export AjaxRequest
 * @class AjaxRequest
 * @extends {AjaxRequest}
 */
export default class AjaxRequest {

    /**
     * Creates an instance of AjaxRequest.
     * @param {any} { url, type, contentType, cache, processData, data, successCallback, errorCallback } 
     * 
     * @memberOf AjaxRequest
     */
    constructor({ url, type, contentType, cache, processData, data, successCallback, errorCallback }) {
        Guard.throwIf(url, "url");
        let emptyFunc = () => {};

        this.url = url;
        this.type = type.toUpperCase() || "GET";
        this.contentType = contentType !== undefined ? contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        this.processData = processData !== undefined ? processData : true;
        this.dataType = "json";
        this.cache = cache || false;
        this.data = data ? JSON.stringify(data) : undefined;
        this.successCallback = successCallback || emptyFunc;
        this.errorCallback = errorCallback || emptyFunc;
    }

    /**
     * Executes the AJAX request.
     * 
     * @memberOf AjaxRequest
     */
    execute() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.url,
            type: this.type,
            contentType: this.contentType,
            processDAta: this.processData,
            dataType: this.dataType,
            cache: this.cache,
            data: this.data,
            success: this.successCallback,
            error: this.errorCallback
        });
    }

    /**
     * Gets a File Upload request.
     * 
     * @static
     * @param {string} url 
     * @param {array} files The files to upload
     * @param {function} successCallback 
     * @param {function} errorCallback 
     * @returns 
     * 
     * @memberOf AjaxRequest
     */
    static fileUpload(url, files, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        let data = new FormData();

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let file = files[i];
            data.append('file', file, file.name);
        }

        return new AjaxRequest({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            processData: false, // Don't process the files
            contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
            successCallback: successCallback,
            errorCallback: errorCallback
        });
    }
}
```

The 'fileUpload' function is called with the target URL and the file list from a file input HTML control in a modal. The console.log at this point indicates that the file list is passed in as expected so the issue is somewhere between these points.

In Chrome I cannot see a Form Data element to the request, which I would expect to see really - I think something is wrong with my data object construction but I can't seem to figure it out.

From Chrome...

```
GENERAL
Request URL:https://localhost:44333/Route/UploadTimetable/60018
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 
Remote Address:[::1]:44333

RESPONSE HEADERS
content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
date:Wed, 08 Mar 2017 18:02:41 GMT
server:Kestrel
status:500
x-powered-by:ASP.NET
x-sourcefiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnRcQ2xpZW50c1xFc290ZXJpeFxNT0RMRSBPcGVyYXRpb25zXHNyY1xFc290ZXJpeC5Nb2RsZS5Qb3J0YWx3ZWJcUm91dGVcVXBsb2FkVGltZXRhYmxlXDYwMDE4?=

REQUEST HEADERS
:authority:localhost:44333
:method:POST
:path:/Route/UploadTimetable/60018
:scheme:https
accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
cache-control:no-cache
content-length:2
content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
cookie: {removed}
origin:https://localhost:44333
pragma:no-cache
referer:https://localhost:44333/Route/60018?Message=The%20route%20details%20have%20been%20updated.
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest

REQUEST PAYLOAD
{}
```

The above I would expect to show Form Data would I not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies with my AjaxRequest constructor here...

```
this.data = data ? JSON.stringify(data) : undefined;
```

needs to only stringify in JSON scenarios (hence it messes up the body) so needs to respond to an extra parameter a bit like this...

```
this.stringify = stringify !== undefined ? stringify : true;
this.data = data && stringify ? JSON.stringify(data) : data;
```

I can then call the constructor and make stringify false.

If I didn't have to wrap my AJAX calls this would have been more obvious but that's a whole other post.